# Box2d Documentation - Outdated, any better api refs?

Tags: documentation, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am working with cocos2d + box2d and as I look through the 'Hello World' tutorial and attempt others I am finding many constructs which do not seem to be documented in the latest api ref.

Would anybody be able to shed some light on what's going on? or point me in the right direction to someone who has covered the new constructs such as b2PolygonDef changing to b2PolygonShape and likewise for circle + who knows what else, seems there has not been any doc updates since August '09.

This is the only information I could find on the issue, of another user stating they have found many mismatches also.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Box2d manual has been updated as at version 2.1.0!

Awesome!

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Answer (score 2):

Have realised the same problem. Am working with cocos2d for iPhone + box2d. The only solution so far is to delve into the box2d SDK code. The .h files are pretty well commented helpful.

Comment: Yeah. Sigh, oh well maybe one day it will get updated!

Comment: Don't count on it. I think Erin's counting on the community to help out with that.